# How to create public html (apache2) with LDAP authentication?

Tags: apache-2.2, ldap

Im running Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04 Server because I want to create a home directory for each ldap user. I'm using LDAP for authentication and it's working ok. Also I've done some tests with LDAP module for Apache2 and it's working ok.

The problem with this LDAP authentication is that any success login can access to ~user/public_html, even if the user is not the *owner* of that home.

I dont know how to control that, for example, userldap2 access to userldap1/public_html. I want that only the userldap1 access to userldap1.

Could anybody tell me how to control that with LDAP authentication?

I hope that you'll understand me.

My config (auth_ldap.conf)

```
 <Directory /home/disco2/*/public_html>
  AuthName "Authentication"
  AuthType basic
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://prueba.borja/dc=prueba,dc=borja?uid?
  Require ldap-filter objectClass=posixAccount
 </Directory>
```

Comment: Most probably because www-data has access to each folder. Check not owner but group of the folder

Answer (score 1):

An option that might work for you is the [mod_authz_owner](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_owner.html) Apache module.  While I *cannot* verify that this works with `AuthBasicProvider ldap`, we do use it with `AuthType CAS`:

```
AuthType CAS
CASAuthNHeader REMOTE_USER
Require file-owner
```

mod_authz_owner will allow you to use the `Require file-owner` option.

Comment: Thanks for you help. 
I've tried some test with "Require file-owner" / ldap-filter, but I can't succeed with anyone, even if I login with the owner.

LDAP users has 'homeDirectory' attribute... could be possible to check with ldapfilter that the ~uid equals the name of the /home/<username>?  I'm stuck with this.

Thanks again!

Comment: I'd appreciate any troubleshooting. I can't go on with this.